# What are the differences between browsers, programmatically?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, opera

Where can I find a breakdown of the difference between web browsers from a developer's prospective?

I always wanted to know what makes IE different than Firefox from Chrome, Opera, etc. Please let me know where I can find this info.

Comment: Do you mean from the perspective of a web developer, or browser developer?

Comment: A web developer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers) for some detailed, useful information such as:

- Image format support
- Plugins and syndicated content support
- JavaScript support
- Operating system support
- Vulnerabilities

All of this information appears to be kept very current about modern browsers.  The article lists some useful information about historical browsers as well.

I imagine that a web developer could find no more informative a comparison without giving up some degree of the breadth afforded by that article.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was actually just reading this one lol.

Answer (score 2):

http://quirksmode.org/ has some VERY long tables on CSS, DOM and JS support.

Comment: In concerns of supporting new HTML5 standards, they have a very detailed comparison at [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome23/opera1210/ie10.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Google's Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main) has a comprehensive comparison of popular browsers from a security & development perspective